# Modifying Section Style modifies the style of Contents in ToC

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, article

In the article class, if the style of the section heading is changed, the style of the contents heading in the Table of Contents is also changed. How to prevent this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,bindingoffset=0.2in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}[block]%
    {
     \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=blue!20,right color=white] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%
    {\thesection}%
    {1em}%
    {}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\section{Limitations of Existing System}
\section{Problem Definition}
\section{Architecture of Proposed System}
\section{Novelty of the Work}
\section{Hardware / Software Tools}
\section{Gnatt Chart}
\section{References}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not relevant to the question, but i think you really mean "Gantt Chart", not "Gnatt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three different options; which one to use will depend on your actual document and your needs:

1. Make the redefinition *after* `\tableofcontents`:

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,bindingoffset=0.2in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded]{geometry}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \begin{document}
   \tableofcontents
   \newpage

   \titleformat{\section}[block]%
       {
        \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=blue!20,right color=white] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%
       {\thesection}%
       {1em}%
       {}
   \section{Introduction}
   \section{Limitations of Existing System}
   \section{Problem Definition}
   \section{Architecture of Proposed System}
   \section{Novelty of the Work}
   \section{Hardware / Software Tools}
   \section{Gnatt Chart}
   \section{References}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Define two commands; one for standard sections and another one for the modified ones; in this way you can switch at will between styles:

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,bindingoffset=0.2in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded]{geometry}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}

   \newcommand\ModSection{%
   \titleformat{\section}[block]%
       {
        \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=blue!20,right color=white] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%
       {\thesection}%
       {1em}%
       {}
   }
   \newcommand\StdSection{%
   \titleformat{\section}
     {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
     {\thesection}
     {1em}
     {}
   }

   \begin{document}

   \tableofcontents
   \newpage
   \ModSection
   \section{Introduction}
   \section{Limitations of Existing System}
   \section{Problem Definition}
   \section{Architecture of Proposed System}
   \section{Novelty of the Work}
   \section{Hardware / Software Tools}
   \section{Gnatt Chart}
   \section{References}
   \end{document}
   ```
3. Define a variant with the default formatting settings with `numberless` to be applied for starred sections (such as the ToC, LoF, LoT):

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,bindingoffset=0.2in,centering,headheight=0.3in,heightrounded]{geometry}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{titlesec}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}

   \titleformat{\section}[block]%
       {
        \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=blue!20,right color=white] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%
       {\thesection}%
       {1em}%
       {}
   \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
     {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
     {}
     {0em}
     {}

   \begin{document}

   \tableofcontents
   \newpage
   \section{Introduction}
   \section{Limitations of Existing System}
   \section{Problem Definition}
   \section{Architecture of Proposed System}
   \section{Novelty of the Work}
   \section{Hardware / Software Tools}
   \section{Gnatt Chart}
   \section{References}
   \end{document}
   ```

Not related to your question, but notice that your current settings for the modified format won't behave well for titles spanning more than one line.